# What is the percentage of goals scored during added time?

Tags: football, trivia, statistics

It could be just me, but I am getting the idea that more and more goals are scored during added time. I would like to see a stat to show if the chance of a goal in added time is higher than in regular time.
For example, up to now CL matches 6x16x90 minutes gave 261 goals during regulation, 1 every 33 minutes.
Extra time had 16 goals in 6x16x5 minutes (sorry, was too lazy to look up the exact minutes of added time played), which is a goal every 30 minutes.

Does anyone have the stats over more matches/leagues/years?

Comment: this could just be based on the scores going into extra time. if it's 2-1 then one team will attack more and there's a good chance it ends 3-1 or 2-2. If it's 1-1 then both teams will usually be happy with a point and not risk losing the game. Also, this last week in the UCL is week 4, and at the stage where teams are playing *must-win* games, so they will throw even more players forward to get those extra points.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about time added on? Statistically a team has more chance of scoring the longer a game goes on. I read an interesting article on it where the writer said a goal in the 80th minute is 40% more likely than a goal in the 10th as an example of how a goal is more likely the longer a game goes on. 
http://statscream.blogspot.ie/2010/04/football-goal-times-in-brief.html
According to an article on the Guardian there has been 3532 goals scored between 81-90+ (the next highest is 2598 in 41-50 mins) so that backs up the other articles claims.
http://www.theguardian.com/football/2013/oct/30/the-knowledge-premier-league-minutes-goals

Comment: He was talking about the goals scored after 90'

Answer (score -1):

Here you can have a list of famous/important Last-minute goals : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last-minute_goal

And here a well-written article about goals in stoppage-time in 2011/2012 I guess (it gives you percentage per team, only Premier League): http://www.pinnaclesports.com/online-betting-articles/11-2012/live-premier-league-betting-tips.aspx

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Stack Exchange discourages redirecting viewers to other places, see [this notice about "other castles"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: @Nicolas that second link doesn't take to article.